# Question on the notation of the interval for which a general solution or equation is defined

Tags: ordinary-differential-equations

when we say that a solution is true for  $-\infty < x < +\infty$ does that mean that it is true for all real numbers or any number between negative infinity and positive infinity, which is quite vague.

Comment: That's the same thing. The set of real numbers is the whole interval $(-\infty,+\infty)$.

Comment: @julien I think that his/her second interpretation is intended to say "a *particular* $x$ value in range $(-\infty, +\infty)$".  At least, that's how I read it... `:)`

Comment: @anorton Hmm...you might very well be right.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

When we say solutions exist for $-\infty \lt x \lt +\infty$, we are saying the solution is valid for *all $x$* in that range.  So, your first statement is the correct interpretation.